# Blazor - redirect to page in another project in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have situation where want to redirect user from page from one project to page in another project, in one solution. Thats important, Im doing in blazor server, anyone can teach me something?

Comment: You should expand your question to describe what you have tried and any errors you are trying to solve.

Comment: [Review] This question needs a lot more detail on what you are trying to achieve with some code showing what you have tried. - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "In one solution" is not relevant at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can always inject NavigationManager - With this you can redirect a user to another component or any URI- so would probably work for your situation:

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationmanager
            
 @code
 {    
        private void NavigateToGoogle()
        {
                navigationmanager.NavigateTo("https://www.google.com", true);
        }
        
  }
```

Check this out for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers